# How to make my Connection string universal in C#, aka how to make it usable for every user of my app?

Tags: c#, connection-string

Ok, so i am doing my final project for high school in C#. I had to include database for best grade.
My proffesor says she can't start my program because she can't read my database file on her PC. I know that my connection string is using my pc info instead of hers. So how do i make that connection string usable on her PC too? [Picture of my Connection string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvXLc.png) I just want my app to be usable for every PC where it is started on.

Here is my connection string if you can't view picture: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\matij\Desktop\Maturski rad\Maturski rad\bin\Debug\NormaBaza.accdb"

Comment: Does it have to be an MS Access database? An embeded database like SQLite is packaged with your application in the bin folder so there are no path or driver issues. And the code to swtich is a very easy conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) instead of hard coded paths.

Something like this:

```
var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
connection.ConnectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"{localAppdata}\MyAppName\MyDb.accdb\"";
```